# How to pop an item in a list that is a quotation mark

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have an item in list that contains just a quotation mark and a comma (",) and I can't seem to pop that item from the list

I've tried

```
for item in my_list:
    if item == '",':
        my_list.pop(my_list.index(item))
```

I've also tried

```
for item in my_list:
    if item == '\",':
        my_list.pop(my_list.index(item))
```

I've gotten no luck, is there anything I'm missing

Comment: `mylist = [x for x in mylist if x != '",']`

Comment: What you're missing is that you should **never** modify an iterable whilst iterating over it. There are various ways to do this safely but reconstructing the list (as suggested by @Unmitigated) is typically optimum

Comment: You have both `item1` and `item` in your code. That seems to be one problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. "I've gotten no luck, is there anything I'm missing" - this is extremely unhelpful. "I've gotten no luck" is not something we can help with, because a) we [don't "help with"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) anything and b) it does not **describe a problem**. In the future, please make sure to explain **what happened when you tried the code**, and **how that is different** from the expected result.

Comment: "is there anything I'm missing" is not a properly direct question; this is **not a discussion forum**, so instead try to think in terms of questions like "what is wrong with the code?" or better yet, "why does <...> happen at <...> point in the process? I expected <...> instead because <explain your reasoning>".

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two issues:

1. Typically it is frowned upon to modify an iterable while iterating over it. You can iterate over a copy of the list instead, and then modify the original list.
2. You are trying to compare `item1` to something, but `item1` is not defined. You should change this to `item`.

Here is the modified code:

```
my_list = ['",', 'a', 'b', 'c']
for item in my_list.copy():
    if item == '",':
        my_list.pop(my_list.index(item))
        
print(my_list)
```

**Output**

`['a', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not attempt to answer questions that are common duplicates. We have reams of information on the site already about this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```py
element_to_remove = '",'

for _ in range(my_list.count(element_to_remove)):
    my_list.remove(element_to_remove)
```

Comment: What if *element_to_remove* isn't in the list? What if there's more than one occurrence?

Comment: You are right, I have modified the code accordingly